# How put 1st item of ComboBox as already selected?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-10.3-rio

How put 1st item (index **0**) of ComboBox as already selected?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ComboBox1.Items do
  begin
    Add('1st Item');
    Add('2nd Item');
    Add('3rd Item');
  end;
end;

// PS: Change the Style property of ComboBox1 to csOwnerDrawFixed
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  AnIcon: TIcon;
begin
  AnIcon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    ImageList1.GetIcon(Index, AnIcon);
    with Control as TComboBox do
    begin
      Canvas.Draw(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, AnIcon);
      Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + ImageList1.Width, Rect.Top, Items[Index]);
    end;
  finally
    AnIcon.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried `ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `ItemIndex` to 0:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ComboBox1.Items do
  begin
    Add('1st Item');
    Add('2nd Item');
    Add('3rd Item');
  end;
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
end;
```

I have left the `with` clause intact, but as an aside I am not a great fan of them.

I would just point out a "gotcha". If you set `ItemIndex` before adding any items, it won't work because there is no item 0 yet, but it won't throw an error either.

Comment: Amen re "with".